# Battle of Claw Island - "You cannot fire weapon in that direction" error

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am on the quest "Battle of Claw Island" as part of the storyline for my character, and I am on the stage of the quest that requires you to use trebuchets against the enemy ship "The Warmonger".

When I "use" the trebuchet it changers my action bar, giving me an option to turn left, turn right, and fire the weapon, however when I aim in the direction of The Warmonger and press fire I get an error message - "You cannot fire weapon in that direction" - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, it turns out you need to hold down the 'Fire' button (which in this case is #2 on your action bar) for the full duration of the cast, in order for the trebuchet to fire. If you simply press the fire button, it will give you the error message "You cannot fire weapon in that direction", which is a bit misleading.

Comment: Yeah, I beat my head against this for a while too... -_-

Comment: The press and hold mechanic allows you to adjust the range. The shorted the press, the shorter the range.

Comment: Are you sure? I only fired it once in the end, and got a one shot hit on the boat? Guess I am just that lucky... Are there other instances of this mechanic in game?

Comment: thank you soo much for the tips, worked perfect once I pressed and held down on the Fire button!!